# Sunspot rails consumes memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sunspot-solr

I am using sunspot for search in my project. It is taking around 500MB of memory.
I have configured in `production.rb` and set to use 200MB max. But however when I start it, it eats around 350MB.
Following is my config

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    min_memory: 100M
    max_memory: 200M
```

What should I do to avoid sunspot eating memory?
Also what is the minimum memory needed to run `sunspot` properly?